# Google Calendar API: HttpError 400 creating event in google calendar

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-calendar-api

I've made a program which takes my shifts from work and imports them as events into Google Calendar.
It have worked perfectly the last year, but when i ran it today I got a 400 httperror.

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">
```

I have no clue what have caused it to happen. I've read from other forums that it might be something with the timezones, but i haven't changed a single line in this program since it was made. I have updated the chromedriver a few times though.

```
from __future__ import nested_scopes, print_function
import datetime
from os import R_OK
import os.path
from random import Random
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

n = 0
ArbejdsTider = []

# Information
UsernameText = "my email"
PasswordText = "my password"

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", options=options)

# Kom ind på siden
driver.get(
    "https://app.tamigo.com/Shift/Pages/EmployeeShifts.aspx")

# Find username textbox og indsæt username
UsernameInput = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'Username')
UsernameInput.send_keys(UsernameText)

# Find password textbox og indsæt password
PasswordInput = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'Password')
PasswordInput.send_keys(PasswordText)

# Find log-in knap og tryk
LoginBtn = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-btn').click()

# Find tabel
RawData = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="employeeShiftsGrid"]/tbody')

# Gemmer de forskellige vagter i lister [[dag1, tid2], [dag2,tid2], [dag3,tid3]]
for row in RawData.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr"):
    n += 1
    dag = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//*[@id='employeeShiftsGrid']/tbody/tr[{}]/td[4]".format(n)).text
    tid = driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, "//*[@id='employeeShiftsGrid']/tbody/tr[{}]/td[5]".format(n)).text
    ArbejdsTider.append([dag, tid])

# Filtrer dagenavne væk
for x in range(len(ArbejdsTider)):
    ArbejdsTider[x][0] = re.sub('\D', '', ArbejdsTider[x][0])
    ArbejdsTider[x][1] = re.sub('\D', '', ArbejdsTider[x][1])

# Filterer 2-tal væk i tid ved evt. pause i vagten
for x in range(len(ArbejdsTider)):
    if len(ArbejdsTider[x][1]) > 8:
        ArbejdsTider[x][1] = ArbejdsTider[x][1][:-1]

# for x in range(len(ArbejdsTider)):
    # print(ArbejdsTider[x][0])
    # print(ArbejdsTider[x][1])
# driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

creds = None
# The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'C:/Users/rasmu/Desktop/TTC/Calendar/credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())

service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Call the Calendar API
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                      maxResults=100, singleEvents=True,
                                      orderBy='startTime').execute()
events = events_result.get('items', [])

if not events:
    print('No upcoming events found.')
for event in events:
    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
    if event['summary'] == "Arbejde":

        # Slet vagt
        service.events().delete(calendarId='primary',
                                eventId=event['id']).execute()
        # print("Delete the event and create a new one")
    # print(start, event['summary'])

for x in range(len(ArbejdsTider)):
    tidspunkt = str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][4]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][5])
    STARTÅR = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][4]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0]
                  [5]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][6]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][7]))
    STARTMÅNED = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][2]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][3]))
    STARTDAG = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][0]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][1]))
    STARTTIME = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][0]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][1]))
    STARTMINUT = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][2]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][3]))
    SLUTÅR = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][4]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0]
                 [5]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][6]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][7]))
    SLUTMÅNED = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][2]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][3]))
    SLUTDAG = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][0] + str(ArbejdsTider[x][0][1])))
    SLUTTIME = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][4]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][5]))
    SLUTMINUT = int(str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][6]) + str(ArbejdsTider[x][1][7]))
    # Vagt slutter efter midnat
    if int(tidspunkt) >= 0 and int(tidspunkt) < 4:
        event = {
            'summary': 'Arbejde',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:00'.format(STARTÅR, STARTMÅNED, STARTDAG, STARTTIME, STARTMINUT),
                'timeZone': 'GMT+02:00',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:00'.format(SLUTÅR, SLUTMÅNED, SLUTDAG+1, SLUTTIME, SLUTMINUT),
                'timeZone': 'GMT+02:00',
            }
        }
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()

        # Vagt slutter før midnat
    else:
        event = {
            'summary': 'Arbejde',
            'start': {
                'dateTime': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:00'.format(STARTÅR, STARTMÅNED, STARTDAG, STARTTIME, STARTMINUT),
                'timeZone': 'GMT+02:00',
            },
            'end': {
                'dateTime': '{}-{}-{}T{}:{}:00'.format(SLUTÅR, SLUTMÅNED, SLUTDAG, SLUTTIME, SLUTMINUT),
                'timeZone': 'GMT+02:00',
            }
        }
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
```

Comment: to start with i would check your refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

The error code **400** indicates that a required field or parameter has not been provided, the value supplied is invalid, or the combination of provided fields is invalid.

You can replicate the error by providing either one of these in the **dateTime** value of your request body:

- *empty string*
- *day > 31*
- *month > 12*
- *hours >  23*
- *minutes > 59*

**Example:**

Invalid date:

[image]

Output:

```
An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest', 'message': 'Bad Request'}]">
```

To resolve the issue, make sure to validate the values being passed to the **dateTime** section of your code.

### Reference:

- [Google Calendar API 400 Error code](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#400_bad_request)